# Run DeepGraphGO main program and report path error

Tags: python, bioinformatics

DeepGraphGO
https://github.com/yourh/DeepGraphGO
Run the main program

```
Using backend: pytorch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/deepgrago210721/main.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\deepgrago210721\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\deepgrago210721\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\deepgrago210721\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "D:\Users\...\PycharmProjects\deepgrago210721\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/deepgrago210721/main.py", line 31, in main
    data_cnf, model_cnf = yaml.load(Path(data_cnf)), yaml.load(Path(model_cnf))
  File "D:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1038, in __new__
    self = cls._from_parts(args, init=False)
  File "D:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 679, in _from_parts
    drv, root, parts = self._parse_args(args)
  File "D:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 663, in _parse_args
    a = os.fspath(a)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
```

Ask for help,I failed to find the reason. Is it because of the data storage location?

Comment: Did you pass the Path of dataset configure yaml and Path of model configure yaml when you ran the main file as -d and -m?

Comment: You mean this ```File "D:/Users/.../PycharmProjects/deepgrago210721/main.py", line 31, in main
    data_cnf, model_cnf = yaml.load(Path(data_cnf)), yaml.load(Path(model_cnf))```?I'm a novice. I don't know much here

Comment: how did you run main.py? what are the arguments you passed?

Answer (score 0):

The steps to run the [DeepGraphGO](https://github.com/yourh/DeepGraphGO): graph neural network for large-scale, multispecies protein function prediction

step 1:
Clone/Download the [repo](https://github.com/yourh/DeepGraphGO/archive/refs/heads/master.zip)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install dtrx
```

step 2:
Extract Data folder

```
cd ./data
dtrx -f data.zip
```

step 3:
Run the preprocessing script

```
python preprocessing.py data/ppi_mat.npz data/ppi_dgl_top_100
```

Run the main function with different model-id with biological process ontology domain, for molecular function ontology and cellular component ontology domains replace the yaml files in `-d with configure/mf.yaml and configure/cc.yaml` respectively

```
python main.py -m configure/dgg.yaml -d configure/bp.yaml --model-id 0
python main.py -m configure/dgg.yaml -d configure/bp.yaml --model-id 1
python main.py -m configure/dgg.yaml -d configure/bp.yaml --model-id 2
```

Run the evaluation script for BP domain

```
python bagging.py -m configure/dgg.yaml -d configure/bp.yaml -n 3
python evaluation.py data/bp_test_go.txt results/DeepGraphGO-Ensemble-bp-test.txt
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I run the project in pycharm under windows. What should I do to extract the data in the second step? I think there may be something wrong with my step

Comment: Extract the contents of the data.zip in the same directory using any unzipping software

Comment: but step 3: Run the preprocessing script run after:```  File "preprocessing.py", line 34
    ppi_net_mat = (mat_:=ssp.load_npz(ppi_net_mat_path)) + ssp.eye(mat_.shape[0], format='csr')
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: use python 3.8 or greater

Comment: That's what I use Requirements

    python==3.8.3 I really don't know what's wrong

Comment: can you confirm ```ppi_mat.npz``` file in your /data directory?